# Override vendor/company/module/src/ files

Tags: magento2, overrides

I have a custom module installed via composer and the path is `vendor/company/module/src/registration.php`.

I want to override some of these files like  `vendor/company/module/src/view/template/frontend/main.phtml` but no path I tried worked:

```
app/code/Company/Module/src/view/template/frontend/main.phtml
app/code/Company/Module/view/template/frontend/main.phtml
app/design/frontend/package/theme/Company_Module/src/view/template/frontend/main.phtml
app/design/frontend/package/theme/Company_Module/view/template/frontend/main.phtml
```

I hope there is an easy way to do it and you don't have to create a separate module and extend.

Comment: You can override by using theme as you mentioned , is there any issue using themes.

Comment: @krishnaijjadaati95Dev yes, it doesn't get parsed, inserted die() or incorrect php syntax.

Comment: @krishnaijjadaati95Dev deleted var folder and flushed cache

Comment: @ Claudiu Creanga first test whether the module is working or not, then you can migrate the templates into theme

Comment: @krishnaijjadaati95Dev the module is working properly. if I go to `website.com/module-url` it is showing up properly. if I edit main.phtml in vendor the change is being picked up, but not if I edit ../theme/..

Comment: @krishnaijjadaati95Dev triple checked the spelling. did you override a custom module from vendor and it was working? if so, did you include /src/ in the path?

Comment: I am trying, will get back to you

Comment: Please check the answer with example and i observed "template" should be "templates".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy templates folder from

```
template/frontend/main.phtml
```

Keep your code in

```
app/design/frontend/package/theme/Company_Module/template/frontend/main.phtml
```

**What i have tried**
Taken the code from

```
\vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\form\login.phtml
```

And placed

```
\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\Magento_Customer\templates\form\login.phtml
```

Working as expected.

Comment: yes, disregarded view/frontend and it worked. thanks!

Comment: and I guess if I want to override Block/Phpfile.php i will have to extend

Comment: it makes sense though so that composer can update it properly

Comment: Yes, as well as you know if you want to override only few functions use PLUGIN, or entire class use preference by extending core class.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Magento 2.2 & 2.3
You have to place your code in

```
app/design/frontend/package/theme/Company_Module/templates/main.phtml
```

where Company_Module is the name on etc/module.xml, and no need to put frontend again after module namen and the name of folder is "templates*" and no "template"

Another exemple to override

```
vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-catalog/view/frontend/web/template/autocomplete/category.html
vendor/smile/elasticsuite/src/module-elasticsuite-core/view/frontend/web/template/autocomplete/term.html
```

Override has to be on two different modules and on web folder

```
app/design/frontend/Package/Name/Smile_ElasticsuiteCore/web/template/autocomplete/term.html
app/design/frontend/Package/Name/Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalog/web/template/autocomplete/category.html
```